# I want to get the api values using json.if I click the json button I did not get any response

Tags: php

I want to get the api values using json. if I click the json button I did not get any response I don't know why this is not running yesterday I have checked with api method it is in post only.I don't know where i am lacking.
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function json()
{
    xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url="http://new.ezeeinfosolutions.com/busservices/auth/getAuthToken?namespaceCode=demo&username=ram@demo.com&password=newnew&devicemedium=WEB";
    alert(url);
    //var url="dbarr.php";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var ret_arr=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            json_arr(ret_arr);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
function json_arr(x)
{
    var res="";
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        res+=x[i].name+" "+x[i].mobile+"</br>";
    }
    document.getElementById('print').innerHTML=res;
}
</script>

<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" onClick="json();" value="Json">
<p id="print"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

i can suppose what "http://new.ezeeinfosolutions.com" isnt your domain and you nead create some php mirror file on your server.

This file will get response from http://new.ezeeinfosolutions.com and return json.

Answer (score 0):

their can few possible solution, if any of them get you to success than chear up :)

1. try to set response type.

   xmlhttp.responseType = 'json';
2. try to use xmlhttp.response instead of xmlhttp.responseText
3. use this example to compare.

   ```
   var getJSON = function(url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
     var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined'
       ? new XMLHttpRequest()
       : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
     xhr.open('get', url, true);
     xhr.responseType = 'json';
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       var status;
       var data;
       // http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate
       if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // `DONE`
         status = xhr.status;
         if (status == 200) {
           successHandler && successHandler(xhr.response);
         } else {
           errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
         }
       }
     };
     xhr.send();
   };

   getJSON('https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/ip', function(data) {
     alert('Your public IP address is: ' + data.ip);
   }, function(status) {
     alert('Something went wrong.');
   });
   ```

   Read More:https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/xhr-responsetype-json